Laravel telescope logs "list" console command every minute without trigger
I'm encountering an issue with Laravel Telescope in my local development environment where it logs a console command named list every minute, even though my application isn't explicitly triggering it.
Image #1
Image #2
Environment:
Laravel version: v11.22.0
Laravel Sail for local development in WSL2 (in devcontainer)
Telescope installed only in the local environment
OS: Linux

Every minute, Telescope logs a console command entry for list. This is cluttering my logs, and I can't figure out what is triggering it. I haven't set any scheduled tasks or cron jobs that should be running this command.
I've searched through my application code but found no references to list being executed manually. I also tried disabling Telescope temporarily, and the logs stopped showing the command, so it seems related to Telescope.
Steps I've taken:
Checked all cron jobs (none related to list)
Verified that no other processes are triggering the list command
Looked through my codebase for possible causes but found nothing

Has anyone encountered a similar issue, or does anyone know why Telescope might be logging this?

Can anyone help me?

I have the same issue. You can add this to the Telescope configuration file so it doesn't show:
'watchers' => [
    \Laravel\Telescope\Watchers\CommandWatcher::class => [
        'enabled' => env('TELESCOPE_COMMAND_WATCHER', true),
        'ignore' => [
            'list',
        ],
    ],
],


Thank you. For the moment I have implemented the workround you suggested. However, I opened an issue on github of the extension that causing the problem. Let's hope it gets resolved

I had the same issue and found that the Laravel Extra Intellisense VS Code extension was triggering the list command about every minute. Disabling this extension solved the problem but may limit some autocompletion features added by this extension.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=amiralizadeh9480.laravel-extra-intellisense

Thank you very much! I use this extension and it was indeed the cause of the problem. However, instead of disabling it, I decided to implement the workaround suggested by @jsamaniegog

I agree that @jsamaniegog's workaround is better than disabling the extension for now. As you may know, Laravel is about to release its own full-featured VS Code extension, which will replace the need for the other ones. It's going to be great for VS Code users!

Really? I wasn't aware of it. Let's hope it gets released soon then.

At the last Laracon US, there was a quick demo of what is coming. Here's the YT link to this talk: https://youtu.be/AwWepVU5uWM?si=GFRG0novefIjrNBF&t=392
